# Redirect to custom url after login

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I user Spring security + Angular in my application.
And in the spring-security.xml following form login is specified

```
<security:form-login
               always-use-default-target="true"
               login-page="/login"
               default-target-url="/login"
               login-processing-url="/perform_login"
               authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
               username-parameter="username"
               password-parameter="password"
               />
```

And this will redirect the user to login page which is working fine as expected.

But now I want to enhance it to remember the url before login and after successful login redirect to that page

**Expected scenario**

1. Application is logged out
2. user type the url : http://WEB-SITE/ReportModule/#/report
3. user is redirected to login page
4. Once the user logged in successfully it is redirected to http://WEB-SITE/ReportModule/#/report

Tried solutions

Tried to save the url in to the session and after login redirect the user.
problem in this solution is when the  http://WEB-SITE/ReportModule/#/report entered to the browser application is redirected to http://WEB-SITE/login/#/report so the part of the url (ReportModule/#/report) is missing to store.

Are there any way to achieve this

Answer:

Found the solution  by using AuthenticationSuccessHandler and useReferer

```
<bean id="AuthenticationSuccessHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="useReferer" value="true"/>
    </bean>
<security:form-login
                always-use-default-target="true"
                login-page="/login"
                default-target-url="/login"
                login-processing-url="/perform_login"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
                username-parameter="username"
                password-parameter="password"
                authentication-success-handler-ref="AuthenticationSuccessHandler"
                />
```

Comment: Have you tried with the [HTTP referer header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)? It show you where the original call started

Answer (score 0):

Hello I am not sure about your frontend solution for protecting the urls.I assume you are uing guards for redirecting the  user.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
        // logged in so return true
        return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url and return false
    this.router.navigate(['login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
    return false;
}
```

}

this.router.navigate(['login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }}); This is what you are looking for.